# firebase' is not defined no-undef firebase error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

Can't use Firebase in react app, I installed Firebase using **npm install firebase** and created Firebase project. And I added the code provide by Firebase.

```js
    // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
    import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
    // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries
    
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "xxxxxx",
      authDomain: "xxxxx",
      projectId: "xxxx",
      storageBucket: "xxxx",
      messagingSenderId: "xxxx",
      appId: "xxxx"
    };
    
    // Initialize Firebase
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    
    // export
    export const auth = firebase.auth();
    export const googleAuthProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
```

then I used it in react component like below

```js
    import {auth} from '../../firebase';
```

and it says can't compile like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kmaed.png)

Comment: Are you importing a module named `firebase` in the first part, where you reference properties of a `firebase` object?

Comment: actually its export part only its not the whole file

Comment: Can you include your `import` statements as well? This would help to see what could be going wrong. For example you may have imported as `Firebase` rather than `firebase`, or only imported certain parts of the library.

Comment: i think its should be okay now

Comment: Yeah, there is no object named `firebase` declared or imported in your code.

Comment: i installed firebase to node modules using npm command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the new [Firebase Modular SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) which does not use `firebase.` namespace (same for importing AuthProviders). To initialize Firebase auth you must import `getAuth()` function from `firebase/auth` as shown below:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"
import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth"

const firebaseConfig = {...};
    
// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    
// export
export const auth = getAuth(app);
// initialize this way ^^^
export const googleAuthProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
```